# Dynamically Loading A .NET DLL Wrapping A C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have a .NET library which wraps a C++ dll:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public void CallFoo()
    {
        Foo();
    }

    [DllImport("Unmanaged.dll"), EntryPoint = "foo", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void Foo();
}
```

I am able to call the method if i add the wrapper dll to a .NET project. However, if i try to call the method dynamically as below, I got the DLLNotFoundException (which tells me "Unmanaged.dll" couldn't found).

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Wrapper.dll");
Type type = assembly.GetTypes()[0];
dynamic wrapper = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
wrapper.CallFoo();
```

In Visual Studio, "Unmanaged.dll" is not shown as loaded in Modules section. Therefore, i assume that i should find a way to load "Unmanaged.dll".

I am open to any suggestion.

Edit: "Unmanaged.dll" is in the same directory as "Wrapper.dll".

Comment: Use a post-build event to xcopy the DLL into the same directory as your .exe so Windows can always find it.  Note the likely Entrypoint is "_foo" or "?foo@@YAXXZ".

Comment: I am sure the entry point is correct. Also I forgot to mention that unmanaged.dll is in the same directory.

Comment: Then you are probably missing another DLL that "Unmanaged.dll" has a dependency on.  Like the CRT.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see your program trying to find it and failing at it.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, you are right. unmanaged.dll has dependent on another dll. You can answer it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your "Unmanaged.dll" is also dependent on another dll, you'll still get the same exception. It is kinda misleading, however if you will add the DLL's that are dependent to the working directory, your problem may be solved.